# How to query a table column into an array with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, html.listboxfor

I am just trying to use multiselect options in MVC by using ListBoxFor. I created my viewmodel and passing that viewmodel to view. But I found out that I need to create an array list to pass to view and when the results is posted back to controller I will be able to find out what has been selected and save those in the table. So I have a table called ArtistTypes and I would like to get the array list of artistTypeID from this table and pass it to view. I cannot figure it out how to query it to an array?

```
int[] selectedIds = _db.ArtistTypes.ToList().Select(x=> new int[]???);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this

```
int[] selectedIds = _db.ArtistTypes.Select(x=> x.artistTypeID).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just accomplish by

```
int[] selectedIds = A.Select(x => x.ArtistId).ToArray();
```

But i will **recommend** you to use this

```
IEnumerable<int> selectedIds = A.Select(x => x.ArtistId);
```

because an **Array** also implement **IEnumerable**.

Comment: I do not get the 'because' part. It does not really satisfy why you would use an `IEnumerable`.